# autotools/eclipse cant find my include directory

Tags: eclipse, include, autotools

Using eclipse to create an Autotools-based project.

Starting from the "Hello World C++ Autotools Project" in the project creation wizard.
Here are the following steps.

1. Add a folder to the project called `include`.
2. Add a file to the `include` folder called `Application.h`.
3. Add `#include <Application.h>` entry into the `src/proj.cpp` file.
4. Trying to compile gets me a `fatal error: Application.h: No such file or directory`.

What is the autotools-fu I need to add my `include` folder to `-I` search path?

Answer (score 0):

The Autotools plugin sorta follows the design of the GNU autoconf toolset, and so you need to configure the source files that are used by autoconf, automake, etc.

- Start with the Autotools hello world project (I named mine AutoHello)
- Project->New->Source folder->Folder name: `include`
- Add the header file `Application.h` to the `include` folder. I just generated a new simple one, but you can copy an existing one too.
- Add *include/Makefile* to the **AC_CONFIG_FILES** definition in `configure.ac`.  (Note: *.ac files can be thought of as **a**uto**c**onf source files)
- Add *include* to the **SUBDIRS** definition in `Makefile.am` (Note: *.am files can be thought of as **a**uto**m**ake source files)
- Add a new file `include/Makefile.am` which will handle the automake behavior of the `include` folder.
- Add a definition **include_HEADERS** to `include/Makefile.am` which lists all the headers contained in the folder.  For this little example we simply list *Application.h*
- In `src/Makefile.am`, add a definition **a_out_CPPFLAGS**.  Give it a value of *-I$(top_srcdir)/include*.  This tells our make target to add `include` as an include search path when compiling.
- Project->Reconfigure Project

And that *should* give you a project that will compile a target that uses header files that are located in the `include` folder.